# How do I delegate subdomain as a new Hosted Zone in different AWS account?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Domain for my web application let's say domain.com exists in AWS account `A`, which is where production environment is hosted. I want to create multiple QA environments in AWS account `B` for security reasons. I'm trying to have env1.qa.domain.com, env2.qa.domain.com etc in account `B`. I know it is possible to delegate a subdomain to another hosted zone that resides in different account than apex HZ, but I don't know how it can be done. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create the new hosted zone as say "qa.domain.com" or "env1.qa.domain.com" depending on what matches your needs. Note the Name Servers listed at the TOP of the Route 53 zone in the console (i.e. expand "Hosted zone details"). These should match the NS record, but I always grab the values from the top.

Then go into the "domain.com" zone an create a NS record for "qa.domain.com" or "env1.qa.domains.com", whatever matches the zone you created.